# Infinite loop on Geo Redirect

Tags: infinite-loop, redirect, geoip

I have 3 websites for different regions having their own location specific content:

- French website: http://dev.logichub.net/demo/fr/
- German website: http://dev.logichub.net/demo/de/
- Default website: http://dev.logichub.net/demo/

I would like to redirect the visitors to the respective website on the basis of their IP address. For example, if a user lands on http://dev.logichub.net/demo/fr/ from Germany, then he/she must be redirected to German website i.e. http://dev.logichub.net/demo/de/. I would like to implement this same behaviour on all the 3 websites.

I put the following code on the homepage on these 3 websites:

```
// get visitor IP address and process
$geo_data = unserialize( file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) );

if ( ! empty( $geo_data ) ) {

    switch ( $geo_data['geoplugin_countryCode'] ) {

            // redirect French visitors to FR website
            case "FR":
                echo '<script>window.location.replace( "http://dev.logichub.net/demo/fr/" );</script>';
                break;

            // redirect German visitors to DE website
            case "DE":
                echo '<script>window.location.replace( "http://dev.logichub.net/demo/de/" );</script>';
                break;

            // redirect all others to international website
            default:
                echo '<script>window.location.replace( "http://dev.logichub.net/demo/" );</script>';
    }
}
```

It works fine exactly like I want except the infinite loop on the redirected website. The visitor is redirected perfectly, but the new website load forever. How can I stop the infinite loop so once visitor redirected to the correct website, no more redirection occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check if the user is on the right domain before trying to redirect. Here's a solution fully made in PHP:

```
<?php
session_start();

$currentUrl = explode('/', "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]");
$currentCountry = isset($currentUrl[4]) ? $currentUrl[4] : '';

if(empty($_SESSION['country'])) {
    $geo_data = unserialize( file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) );

    if(!empty($geo_data)) {
        $country = $geo_data['geoplugin_countryCode'];
        $_SESSION['country'] = $country = ($country != 'FR' || $country != 'DE') ? '' : $country;
    }
}

if($currentCountry != $_SESSION['country'])
    header('Location: http://dev.logichub.net/demo/'.$country);
```

You could improve this code by getting the current country without searching it in the URL (by defining it in the file, for example), but actually, it should work better.

Comment: Thanks for the help. What is the purpose of session here? These are 3 different standalone websites. Forgot to include the fact that I am adding this code in functions.php of currently active theme using WordPress.

Comment: It prevent you from keep using the API, will save the final user, the request time related to the webServices